# asp.net - Response.Redirect redirected to wrong relative URL path

Tags: asp.net, url, relative-path, response.redirect

My Response.Redirect does not redirects to the right relative path, or rather, the context root was removed.

Example:

**Initiating URL:** www.abc.com/test/test1/test2.aspx

```
// Inside test2.aspx.vb
Response.Redirect("123.aspx");
```

**Expected:** www.abc.com/**test**/test1/123.aspx

**Actual:** www.abc.com/test1/123.aspx

What else am I missing? Where else can I check?

Comment: what is the root folder of your asp.net website? Did you try `Response.Redirect("~/123.aspx");`? Or maybe `Response.Redirect("~/test1/123.aspx");` ...it depends a bit on your structure, and where the asp.net site is hosted relative to the domain root.

Comment: Hmm I have not tried the 2 above mentioned yet.. but my root folder was **test**